# Covert String into JSON Objects

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a string

```
$string = "\nManufacturer\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nYves Saint Laurent\n\n\n\nItem Package Dimensions L x W x H\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n11.9 x 7.4 x 7.1 centimetres\n\n\n\nPackage Weight\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n0.23 Kilograms\n\n\n\nItem Dimensions L x W x H\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n5.1 x 5.1 x 15.2 centimetres\n\n\n\nItem Weight\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n0.12 Kilograms\n\n\n\nBrand\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nYSL\n\n\n\nFormat\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nSpray\n\n\n\nVolume\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n125 Millilitres\n\n\n\nScent\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nChypre, Floral\n\n\n\nPet Type\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nWomen\n\n\n\nItem model number\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n123751\n\n\n\nProduct Dimensions\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n5.08 x 5.08 x 15.24 cm; 120 Grams\n\n\n\nASIN\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nB000C1W70S\n\n\n";
```

I want to convert it into json objects just like

```
{
    "detail": {
        "Manufacturer":"Yves Saint Laurent",
        "Item Package Dimensions L x W x H":"11.9 x 7.4 x 7.1 centimetres",
        "Package Weight":"0.23 Kilograms",
        "Item Dimensions L x W x H":"5.1 x 5.1 x 15.2 centimetres",
        "Item Weight":"0.12 Kilograms",
        "Brand":"YSL",
        "Format":"Spray",
        "Volume":"125 Millilitres",
        "Scent":"Chypre, Floral",
        "Pet Type":"Women",
        "Item model number":"123751",
        "Product Dimensions":"5.08 x 5.08 x 15.24 cm; 120 Grams",
        "ASIN":"B000C1W70S"
    }
}
```

so far I have tried this:

```
$str = str_replace("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n",':',$string);
$json->detail = str_replace('\"','"',str_replace("\n","",(explode("\n\n\n\n",$str))));
```

but it returns an array so It will be difficult for me to parse the contents from json incase some of the details are missing in string or with wrong sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This first replaces all multiple white space characters with a delimiter ('|' in this case), then explodes on this delimiter to split out all of the fields.

Then it combines alternate values as key/value (using a loop as you need to take the loop in chunks of 2)...

```
$string = preg_replace('!\s{2,}!', '|', trim($string));
$split = explode("|", $string);
$output = [];
for ( $i = 0; $i < count($split); $i+= 2)   {
    $output [$split[$i]] = $split[$i + 1];
}
print_r($output);
```

Comment: Perhaps `$split = preg_split("/\n+/", $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);` might be simpler?